# Selecting unique values from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a SQL query that selects x rows where the columns end up having only unique values.

Table is called keezdrives_played
the columns are called: team_id and opponents_id

[Database Picture.][1]

This is how it should look like: 
[Example][2]

Where team_id and opponents_id have unique values

Comment: use distinct(oppnents_id)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT t.team_id ,o.opponents_id FROM yourTAble t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT team_id,opponents_id FROM yourTAble
    GROUP BY opponents_id
    HAVING count(*) = 1
) AS o ON o.team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY t.team_id 
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from yourTable;
+---------+--------------+
| team_id | opponents_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            5 |
|       1 |            6 |
|       2 |            7 |
|       2 |           80 |
|       3 |            9 |
|       4 |           11 |
|       4 |           22 |
|       8 |            5 |
+---------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>     SELECT t.team_id ,o.opponents_id FROM yourTAble t
    ->     INNER JOIN (
    ->         SELECT team_id,opponents_id FROM yourTAble
    ->         GROUP BY opponents_id
    ->         HAVING count(*) = 1
    ->     ) AS o ON o.team_id = t.team_id
    ->     GROUP BY t.team_id
    ->     HAVING count(*) = 1;
+---------+--------------+
| team_id | opponents_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       3 |            9 |
+---------+--------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**see comment**

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) AS cnt , team_id
    -> FROM keezdrives_played
    -> GROUP BY team_id
    -> ;
+-----+---------+
| cnt | team_id |
+-----+---------+
|   4 |    2281 |
|   4 |    2282 |
|   4 |    2283 |
|   4 |    2284 |
|   4 |    2285 |
|   4 |    2286 |
+-----+---------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**one try more**

```
SELECT  team_id,opponents_id
FROM keezdrives_played
GROUP BY CONCAT(team_id, '-', opponents_id)
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

**last try**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.team_id ,t.opponents_id 
    FROM keezdrives_played t
    GROUP BY t.team_id
    ) r
GROUP BY r.opponents_id;
```

Comment: post your sample table as sql dump to help you

Comment: i have add it in my answer. you see that the team_id is not unique. there are 4 rows of each enty

Comment: or do you looking for a unique combination only of both fields

Comment: i have add one try more that gives all uniques over both fields

Comment: @shampally - and again - the last test

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT team_id ,opponents_id  FROM keezdrives_played where drive_id=144;
```

Comment: You have done this two step. This is the first step then second step is distinct first step result then you have got your result. For this reason you have to need subquery.

Comment: I hope if you use subquery then you get your proper result